# column name is not upper case when using ORMLite with Oracle

Tags: oracle, ormlite

I'm using the latest ORMLite to query against Oracle database. I create all DAOs in Spring and have `@DatabaseField(id = true)` annotation for my key field. In Spring configuration my JDBC url is like jdbc:oracle....

But when I execute my query by `queryById(...)` or `queryForEq(...)` etc ORMLite always try to use the column name with lower case and double quotes which defined in my entity class, so that Oracle doesn't like it and throws an exception:

```
(ORA-00904: "id": invalid identifier)
```

Anyone knows the solution?

Comment: What version of ORMLite are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know ORMLite, but according to the [@DatabaseField Javadoc](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html), you can redefine the column name in the annotation:

```
@DatabaseField(id = true, columnName = "ID")
```

Comment: Thx for the answer but this will loose the compatibility to other database like SQLServer, other database may use lower case column name

Comment: ok, then you can do it the other way around : change the Oracle column name from "ID" to "id" : ALTER TABLE X RENAME COLUMN ID TO "id"

Comment: @Eric Citaire please no. That will make everything else harder about using that database. Especially writing adhoc queries to troubleshoot.

Comment: Did you see [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/ormlite/bugs/128/)? Maybe you just need to update ORMLite.

Answer (score 0):

> (ORA-00904: "id": invalid identifier)

In version 4.42 of [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/), we changed the `OracleDatabaseType` to generate uppercase entities.  This should have been `ID`.  I suspect that you are running a lower version of ORMLite and you should consider upgrading.

If this is not the case, please supply your version number and show your entity fields.

Comment: I'm using the latest ORMLite which is 4.45 from Maven repository. My entity fields are something like: private int id with annotation(@DatabaseField(id = true))